# What make the colors in this picture look soft?

Tags: color, style, filter

See this image:

[image]
http://soranootoshimono.wikia.com/wiki/File:46456845235358656364.png

To me it look soft like some sort of low-pass filter but I also can see sharp edge of the image.

I'm curious what make it look softer than others.
And if you can make one from a normal image I also want to know how can you do that?

Comment: Just looks like a slight blur over the entire image to me...I don't see a "sharp edge" anywhere..... either that or my eyes are going.

Comment: @Scott I understand your point I feel the same It's some thing like ![Donald](//i.imgur.com/COSZLDO.jpg) but I think there are other ingredients not just blurriness.

Comment: Well, you're going to need to describe what you mean by "soft" if you aren't referring to the blur. All I see is a surface blur over everything.

Comment: @Scott I'm trying to reproduce the result. If we assume it's just a surface blur: Which window function used to generate this kind of blur? I tried Gaussian without success probably because of the way I mixed blurred layer into the image but I don't think Gaussian is the right one.

Answer (score 3):

The colours are not soft as such, though they are pastels; but the shadows are simply a darker version of the "original", and there are careful use of highlights. Consider the clothes:

[image]

The outlines are trad cartoon-black. If you removed the shadows and kept the black outlines, you would have old-school-western donald-duck-style cartoon.

Really old Donald Duck, has the shadows as an "overlay" of gray-to-black:

[image]

"Modern" (well, to me anyway) versions do the same as manga: shadows are just darker colours of the highlights, hence the softness:

[image]

---

**Edit:**
In response to some of the comment; I actually do not see a blur. What I *do* see, is outlines that are not *entirely* black, and in some cases, the outline colour is *adjusted to fit the "content" of that object.* Note that some of the outlines are brown-ish, others are blue-ish etc.

I could of course be wrong.